# how to call JScript after application image created while creating an native package in maven

Tags: javascript, maven, package, native, pom.xml

I am using maven.
I have an JScript that will create an runtime/jre/lib/ext folder while installing an application because default a self-contained application does not contain full copy of Java Runtime
As i am using an https connection for that i required jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar.
where https connections will not work if jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar is missing

For this i added script -

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>  
    <package>      
        <job id="postImage">  
        <script language="JScript">  
         <![CDATA[  
            var oFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");  
            var oFolder = oFSO.getFolder(".");  
            var from = oFolder.path + "\\MyApp\\lib\\sunjce_provider.jar";  
            var to = oFolder.path + "\\MyApp\\runtime\\jre\\lib\\ext";  
            if (!oFSO.FolderExists(to)) {  
              oFSO.CreateFolder(to);  
            }  
            to += "\\";  
            oFSO.CopyFile(from, to);  
         ]]>  
        </script>      </job>   </package>
```

But how to call this script while creating package from pom.xml? where script should be executed after application image created.Please suggest